# Create an attribute with image upload

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, entity-attribute-value

I am new to magento and don't know from where to start. I'm thinking of an attribute with an image upload option for each attribute option. Basically i want to create an attribute color with its name and image as options, so that i can show color name with its image in filter navigation in front end. can anyone help me with this how to create such custom attribute?

Comment: will these images be dependent on product?

Comment: You could always use a text attribute and simply enter a CSS color value which would be used in templates to set that color style.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.johannreinke.com/en/2012/02/05/magento-add-images-to-product-attribute-options/ This is what i'm looking for, but still there is a problem it adds image upload options for every attribute. It would have been better if we can select the attribute to add image option. Anyway thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a "[configurable product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product)" and multiple gallery images.

Example on Magento: [ShopJimmy.com (product)](http://www.shopjimmy.com/boomz-audiotm-portable-personal-speaker.htm)

Comment: i'm looking for some kind of attribute with an image upload option which i want to display in layered filter navigation